# Select row if multiple present values are present in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a search function on a movie database, I want to give the option to search a film with two genres (ie: crime id:6 and adventure id:7)

I basically want to get a row from title if it has genre_id 6 AND 7 present in the title_genre value. Obviously, this query below isn't working (I understand why it's not but I don't know how to fix it).

Any help please?

```
 SELECT * FROM (`title`, `title_genre`) 
 WHERE `title`.`active` = 1  
 AND `title`.`media_id` = title_genre.media_id 
 AND title_genre.genre_id = 6 AND title_genre.genre_id = 7
```

Comment: can you show the table structure ??

Comment: I think you need to use [joins](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `exists` to check the existence of other `genre_id = 7` in `title_genre` and also using `explicit join` makes it much better as

```
select 
t.*,
tg.* 
from title t
join title_genre tg on tg.media_id = t.media_id
where 
tg.genre_id = 6 
and exists(
 select 1 from title_genre tg1 
 where tg1.media_id = t.media_id
 and tg1.genre_id = 7
)
```